# Can extra characters be removed from QR scan output

Tags: qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am attempting to do an inventory of several items that have QR codes. The original manifest I have to reference contain a six digit string of numbers for each item (ex. 456789). However, when I scan the QR code there are extra characters (ex. #:456789;). Is this an issue with the keyboard being used on the scanner? I'm using a WASP WDI4600.Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this question relates to Excel?

Comment: I guess it doesn't explicitly but that is where I am handling the scanned QR's and my solution so far has just been to use a formula to delete the additional characters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably so.

Get [WDI4600 Product Reference Guide](https://www.waspbarcode.com/~/media/pdfs/waspbarcode/products/scanner-pdfs/scanner-manuels/wdi4600-product-reference-guide.ashx?la=en) of [WDI4600 2D Barcode Scanner page](https://www.waspbarcode.com/barcode-scanners/wdi4600-2d-barcode-scanner) and see the Data Editing chapter of the printed page 218 (228 in PDF) and the Data Format chapter 43  of the printed page (53 in PDF).

Of the notified data, '#:' is assumed to be prefix or Label ID, ';' is assumed to be suffix.

You can change the presence or absence of these notifications and the code to be notified by the setting barcode of the reference guide.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for specifically referencing the pages in the manual.